# Separate shell scripts from application in docker container?

Tags: docker

I have a `ftp.sh` script that downloads files from an external ftp to my host. And I have another (java) application that imports the downloaded content into a database. Currently, both runs on the host triggered by a `cronjob` as follows:

`importer.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ftp.sh
java -jar app.jar
```

Now I'd like to move my project to `docker`. From the design point of view: would the `.sh` script and the application reside both in a separate container? Or should both be bundled into one container?

I can think of the following approaches:

- Run the ftp script on host, but java app in docker container.
- Run the ftp script in its own docker container, and the java app in another docker container.
- Bundle both the script and java app in a docker container. Then call a wrapper script with: `ENTRYPOINT["wrapper.sh"]`

So the underlying question is: should each docker container serve only on purpose (*either* download files, or import them)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing files between containers is tricky and I would try to avoid doing that.  It sounds like you are trying to set up a one-off container that does the download, then does the import, then exits, so "orchestrating" this with a shell script in a single container will be much easier than trying to set up multiple containers with shared storage.  If the `ftp.sh` script sets some environment variables then it will be basically impossible to export them to a second container.

From your workflow it doesn't sound like building an image with the file and the import tool is the right approach.  If it was, I could envision a work flow where you ran `ftp.sh` on the host or as the first part of a multi-stage build and then `COPY` the file into the image.  For a workflow that's "download a file then import it into a database, where the file changes routinely" I don't think that's what you're after.

The setup you have now should work fine just packaging it into a container.  I'd give you some generic advice in a code-review context but your last option of stuffing it also into one image and running the wrapper script as the main container process makes sense.

Comment: (Prefer `/bin/sh` to `bash` when it's an option; prefer the POSIX standard `.` to the bash `source` extension, or just directly run `./ftp.sh` if it's not setting environment variables; prefer `CMD` to `ENTRYPOINT` if you don't need both.)

Comment: Indeed my downloaded files changes frequently, and I want to import the updates always to a database.